# MacOS don't use driverless IPP

Tags: mac-osx, cups

we use Debian 12 + cups + avahi and add a printer to it (via IPP and use a driverless-driver for the HP Pagewide 477). We can print without install additional drivers in Debian+KDE, and in Windows 10 use the printserver.

When we add a printer in MacOS(Ventura, 13.5.2) via preferences -> Printer '+' it find it automatically when we add them it always use Postscript Generic driver (without having all the possibilities eg color double-sided, etc) instead of driverless, **BUT** if we add it via <OPEN-A-PDF> -> print and add the same printer it get the correct driver "driverless" with all the possibilities.

The question is why and how can I fix that?